# An interesting Number sequence: 8, 10, 7, ...?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Let's see how many of you can solve this correctly

I found a number sequence puzzle somewhere in the web with interesting logic and a unique strict solution.

8, 10, 7,  12, 5, 16, 3, ?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: Where on the web? Please check the link I provided to see what our expectations for attribution are. For example, a link would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using prime numbers alternately with the sign change.

> ```
> 8  →  10  →   7  →  12  →   5  →  16  →   3
>   (+2)    (-3)    (+5)   (-7)   (+11)   (-13)
> ```

So the next number is

> 3+17=**20**.

Answer (score -1):

I thought:

> 8 and 10 are 18, 7 and 12 are 19, 5 and 16 are 21, and 3 and "21" would be 24.
>
>  This would make +1, +2 and +3.
>
>  Then the row of numbers is 8,10,7,12,5,16,3,21